# Convert date from string format to OLE automation date

Tags: python, python-3.x, date, datetime, ole

I have a date string `21-Apr-2018`. How do I convert this date string into OLE automation date in python? I am using Python v3.6.

Definition of OLE date can be found here.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tooadate(v=vs.110).aspx

> An OLE Automation date is implemented as a floating-point number whose
>   integral component is the number of days before or after midnight, 30
>   December 1899, and whose fractional component represents the time on
>   that day divided by 24. For example, midnight, 31 December 1899 is
>   represented by 1.0; 6 A.M., 1 January 1900 is represented by 2.25;
>   midnight, 29 December 1899 is represented by -1.0; and 6 A.M., 29
>   December 1899 is represented by -1.25.
>
> The base OLE Automation Date is midnight, 30 December 1899. The
>   minimum OLE Automation date is midnight, 1 January 0100. The maximum
>   OLE Automation Date is the same as DateTime.MaxValue, the last moment
>   of 31 December 9999.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are at least a couple of ways. You can calculate manually from OLE origin date, or use a 3rd party library such as [`xlrd`](http://xlrd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

In each case, you will need to convert your string to a `datetime` object.

```
from datetime import datetime
from xlrd import xldate

def datetime2ole(date):
    date = datetime.strptime(date, '%d-%b-%Y')
    OLE_TIME_ZERO = datetime(1899, 12, 30)
    delta = date - OLE_TIME_ZERO
    return float(delta.days) + (float(delta.seconds) / 86400)  # 86,400 seconds in day

def datetime2xl(date):
    date = datetime.strptime(date, '%d-%b-%Y')
    parts = ('year', 'month', 'day', 'hour', 'minute', 'second')
    components = tuple(getattr(date, x) for x in parts)
    return xldate.xldate_from_datetime_tuple(components, 0)

print(datetime2ole('22-Apr-2018'))  # 43212.0
print(datetime2xl('22-Apr-2018'))   # 43212.0
```