# Convert from float to datetime in Python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a dataframe which datatype is float64 and I want to change it to datetime 64. But the result is return to only one day : 1970-01-01 no matter which method I use. Any help please

```
df.product_first_sold_date = [41245,0, 37659.0,40487.0,41701.0,40649.0]
dt.cv = pd.to_datetime(df.product_first_sold_date)
dt.cv
dt.cv2 = df.product_first_sold_date.apply(lambda x: datetime.fromtimestamp(x).strftime('%m-%d-%Y') if x==x else None)
dt.cv2
```

[image]

Comment: What's your expected date for `41245`?

Comment: Add sample data as text format. do not add image.

Comment: Check this - https://stackoverflow.com/q/49956741/6075699

Comment: @QuangHoang: as I check in excel , the expected date for 41245 is 2012-12-02

Comment: @Suzie see my answer below.

Comment: @DishinHGoyani: sorry for that, I edited my post

Comment: Okay, and what is the rule that tells you that the expected date for `41245` should be 2012-12-02? What does the number actually *represent*? The reason everything is showing up as 01-01-1970 for you is because the number is being treated as a number of *seconds* since the "epoch", midnight on that day.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you re dealing with Excel date type which is the number of days since <del>`1900-01-01`</del>, as @Dishin pointed out `1899-12-30`

```
# sample data:
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':[41245,37659,40487]})

# convert - adjust 1900-01-01 to the correct day
df['date'] = pd.to_timedelta(df.date, unit='D') + pd.to_datetime('1899-12-30')
```

Output:

```
        date
0 2012-12-02
1 2003-02-07
2 2010-11-05
```

Comment: I think OLE start from "30 December 1899"

Comment: So 41245 is suppose to be "2012-12-02"